# Bigger than "large" columns in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using portrait orientation for my second display with resolution of 1200x1600. And I have two equal width columns in Bootstrap 3. I want these columns to be stacked when used on portrait orientation and be displayed horizontally on landscape orientation (when width > 1200 px). `col-lg-*` in Bootstrap uses exactly 1200 px as boundary value.

So I need something larger than `lg` (i.e. `col-huge-6`) or redefine boundary width for `col-lg-*` to 1201 px, which is simplier. What is the simpliest way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: customize bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: @ins0 ok, that'll do, thanks. Maybe you should move it to an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just customize bootstrap with your project conditions

http://getbootstrap.com/customize